# Show the latest labels in a bar chart with React.js using react-chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am working on creating a bar chart in React.js using react-chartjs library. I am able to get the bar chart to display but since my data is huge and it is collected for every 10 seconds. The bar chart displays something like

[image: Bar chart image]

My dataset for it looks  like

```
var loadData = [{
    options: {
        elements: {
            rectangle: {
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
              borderSkipped: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top'
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'ETL Load Chart'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip:true,
                    maxTicksLimit:20
                }
           }]
        }
    },
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {

                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                data: []
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

I am updating the the data with the help of a library immutability-helpers

```
case 'GET_LOAD_DATA_RECEIVED': 
            var payload = action.data.payload
            var dataValues = [], labelValues = [];
            payload.forEach(function(item){
                dataValues.push(parseInt(item['recs_upd']) + 1);
                labelValues.push(item['from_ts']);
            })
            return update(state, {
                0: {
                    data: {
                        labels: {
                            $push: labelValues
                        },
                        datasets: {
                            0: {
                                data: {
                                    $push: dataValues
                                }
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
            })
            break;
```

and I am calling the rendering of Chart like

```
<Bar data={this.props.loadInfo[0].data} options={this.props.loadInfo[0].options} width="600" height="250" />
```

I am using `"react-chartjs": "^0.8.0"`, and `"chart.js": "^1.1.1"` I couldn't update to `2.0` in chart.js were I saw something called `showXlabels` being present since `react-chartjs` supports the current version.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Pass only the latest `n` number of data for every 10 seconds.

```
const updatedData = {...this.props.loadInfo[0]}

const newData = {
  data: {
    labels: [...updatedData.labels].reverse().slice(0, 30).reverse(),
    datasets: [...updatedData.datasets].reverse().slice(0, 30).reverse(),
  }
}

const newLimitedData = {...updatedData, ...newData }

<Bar data={newLimitedData.data} options={newLimitedData.options} width="600" height="250" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is an option but in this case I will have to have a login in the reducer to also dump the old data and that will be complicated. I want to achieve it with chart.js only. Here is a link which demostrates it using chart.js but I can't figure out how to use it with react-chartjs http://jsbin.com/yitep/5/edit?html,css,js,output. Anyways thanks for your help

Comment: Old data will be always available in `this.props.loadInfo[0]`

Comment: Exactly, after a certain time there will be too much data collected which is also undesirable since it is not getting used anywhere. What I guess is that, the link of the jsbin demo doesn't have this problem. Presently I have done the same fix as you have suggested. But I want it to be temporary will I get a good answer

Comment: If you use `$push: labelValues` in the reducer. I don't think theres a way to avoid dumping data in the store. You should clear the data after a timeout